# OpenCV not working with different RTSP streaming URLs. grab() from videocapture is always 0

Tags: opencv, video-capture, opencv3.0

I'm working with opencv to read the frames from a RTSP streaming link via VideoCapture function. It worked well for a specific RTSP camera. But the thing is, I have tried to connect different RTSP cameras in the same network but for my surprise, it wouldnt work.
Any thoughts of what could cause this problem? I need to be able to get the stream of any rtsp url with the same openCV code for my purpose.

The camera that worked is a generic chinese one and it also worked with the big buck bunny comic provided by rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov. The second camera that I tried and got no outputs is an AirCam Dome from Ubiquiti wich has 4 rtsp links. I tried every resolution.

Comment: Can you access the camera not through OpenCV? It's good to rule out any network errors if it was working locally and now not working remotely. I would suggest trying something like VLC as it uses similar commands to connect as OpenCV

Comment: Yes, all the links are working properly on VLC. But openCV only grabs the frames from the first camera. I would like to be able to catch any h264 encoded via RTSP with openCV so I can easily put different cameras in the system.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have 'opencv_ffmpeg341.dll' or something like this in your running folder.

If you are using Windows system, put the dll in x64 or x86 folder.